# After changing to Oracle Java on Netbeans bottom of text is now cut off Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, java, oracle, netbeans

I recently changed over to the Oracle JDK due to my interest in learning JavaFX, and after doing so upon changing the path for Netbeans and reopening, the text in the left panel and in the new project wizard is now cut off in weird ways.

I tried solving the issue by uninstalling Netbeans to no avail, and even went as far as to uninstall Netbeans (including configurations), then the JDK and reinstall both. The issue is still persisting and it seems I do not have the knowledge to solve it, any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Image showing the issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change font and font size from Gnome Tweak Tool. 
Try different font other than default font.
Change fonts. (windows Title, interface, documents )

And then,
Close Netbeans then restart lightdm. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> write <kbd>r</kbd>. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Open netbeans it should work.

Comment: Didn't get a chance to try this out, but if this works for anyone else let me know and I'll accept as the answer

Comment: It worked for me and for my friend...

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by changing NetBeans settings.

GoTo: Tools -> Option -> Appearance -> Look and Feel and select "Preferred Look and Feel" = Metal (was GTK+ by default) and check "Maximaze use of native look and feel".

Then restart IDE and all menus were OK. Play with IDEs settings there to see what works for you.

Comment: Yes! And checking "Maximize use of native look and feel" was not necessary for me.